# Is there a tool for creating an E2E test with IME support in a web app?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, e2e-testing

We built a web based text editor with IME support and now we want to add some E2E tests to our application that should check the IME behaviour. My question is that if someone here knows which tool may we use for coding such E2E tests or if we should follow another approach like using recording macros apps like AutoIt.

Thanks a lot!

PS: We are currently taking a look to Selenium Web Driver but we are not sure if it will work

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this elsewhere?

Comment: The only thing that worked for us was the Ranorex tool (https://www.ranorex.com/). A professional macro tool with IME support. The counterside is that this tool is not cheap at all and runs only in Windows.